# Warnings in Regular Expression with Posix Collating Elements

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to run following regular expression based function in php where in the end am returning the output.

```
function vg_excerpt_more( $output ) {

    $string = $output;

    $pattern_auto_excerpt = '#([...]</p>)$#';
    $pattern_manual_excerpt = '#(</p>)$#';

    $replacement = ' <a href="'.get_permalink().'">[Continue...]</a></p>';

    if ( preg_match( $pattern_auto_excerpt, $string ) ) {

        $pattern = $pattern_auto_excerpt;

    } else if ( preg_match( $pattern_manual_excerpt, $string ) ) {

        $pattern = $pattern_manual_excerpt;

    }   

    $output = preg_replace( $pattern, $replacement, $string );

    return $output;

}
add_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'vg_excerpt_more' );
add_filter( 'excerpt_more', 'vg_excerpt_more' );
```

Well, the string could either end in `[...]</p>` OR `</p>` so I have to check the two cases.

The problem is, it is throwing warnings as -

> WARNING: PREG_MATCH(): COMPILATION FAILED: POSIX COLLATING ELEMENTS
>   ARE NOT SUPPORTED AT OFFSET 1 in - 'preg_match( $pattern_auto_excerpt,
>   $string )'

**and**

> WARNING: PREG_REPLACE(): EMPTY REGULAR EXPRESSION in - '$output =
>   preg_replace( $pattern, $replacement, $string );'

**EDIT:**

After useful replies by @user1852180 I moved ahead and did this -

```
function vg_excerpt_more( $output ) {


    $string = $output;

    $pattern = '';

    // $pattern_auto_excerpt = '#(\[...\]</p>)$#';

    $pattern_auto_excerpt = '#(\[(?:\.|…)+\])#';
    $pattern_manual_excerpt = '#(</p>)$#';

    $replacement = ' <a href="'.get_permalink().'">[Continue...]</a></p>';

    if ( preg_match( $pattern_auto_excerpt, $string ) ) {

        $pattern = '#(\[(?:\.|…)+\]</p>)$#';

        if ( preg_match( $pattern, $string ) ) {
            return preg_replace( $pattern, $replacement, $string ) . "Dummy2";
        }

    } else if ( preg_match( $pattern_manual_excerpt, $string ) ) {

        $pattern = $pattern_manual_excerpt;
        return preg_replace( $pattern, $replacement, $string ) . "Dummy";

    }

    return $output;

}
add_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'vg_excerpt_more' );
add_filter( 'excerpt_more', 'vg_excerpt_more' );
```

But am still seeing `[...]` in the frontend along with the replacement.

PS. It also never prints 'Dummy2', always 'Dummy'.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the brackets in the first pattern, and the dot:

```
$pattern_auto_excerpt = '#(\[(?:\.|…)+\]</p>)$#';
```

You don't need to use the if/else to check if it has [...], let regex check that with the question mark:

```
function vg_excerpt_more( $output ) {

    $pattern = '#(?:\[(?:\.|…)+\])?</p>$#';
    $replacement = ' <a href="'.get_permalink().'">[Continue...]</a></p>';

    return preg_replace( $pattern, $replacement, $output );

}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. In my case, the string could either end with `[..]</p>` or only `</p>`. Sorry for the confusion, I edited the main question too. 

Will your code check both conditions?

Comment: My first code should fix your warnings, by escaping the brackets. My second code is an example on a smaller code to do the same as yours, by using a question mark in the regex pattern, so it will work with strings that end with [...]</p> and only </p>.

Comment: Thanks. but upon testing I see that `[...]` still shows along with the replacement.

Comment: I have seen some WordPress use ellipsis (a three dot punctuation: `…`). You can try to replace `\[...\]` with `\[(?:\.|…)+\]` in the regex pattern, it will match both the ellipsis and three dots.

Comment: I get Dummy2 when testing your new code with the string `[...]</p>`.

Comment: You mean the code that I added recently in the original question?